# Customize ebuild in Gentoo within the portage tree

Tags: gentoo

How can I customize an ebuild in Gentoo without maintaining a customized package in own overlay?

The case is that I need to mark compiled binaries with `paxctl`. But there are about 100 of such packages and I don't want to watch for updates by myself in local overlay.

Portage ebuilds aren't compiled without such marking. Now I have to change their compile flags in `/etc/portage/package.env` directory. PAX-marking is a better solution but I don't know how to do that in Gentoo within the portage tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using portage you can do this with `package.env`. The right place to look for the documentation is http://dev.gentoo.org/~zmedico/portage/doc/portage.html#config-bashrc-ebuild-phase-hooks. Basically the way you use it is as follows. First you create (assuming standard setup without custom `ROOT`) a file in `/etc/portage/env`. For example, you can create a file `/etc/portage/env/paxmark`

```
#paxmark

#Set this to what you need it to be
PAXFLAGS="-p"

post_src_install() {
  find "${INSTALL}" -type x -print0 |xargs -0 -n 1 paxctl $PAXFLAGS
}
```

Then for all packages you want this to apply to you add an entry to `/etc/portage/package.env` :

```
#package.env example for paxmark
sys-apps/gcc paxmark
```

This will apply the `paxmark` script to the package that has it specified. Alternatively you can also create a `/etc/portage/bashrc` script for global overrides (be very careful with that).

A general **warning** though, as you can add pre and post hooks to all phases this can be dangerous. Be careful with what you do as all your packages that use the hook have now become no more robust than your hook script. (The above example for pax marking should be fine).

Comment: Thanks for giving an answer. It will be helpful if you can provide more steps to your answer.

Comment: I've updated the question. Hope this helps more.

Comment: This way causes a portage exception in my case. I've opened a [new question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/218286/39172)

Answer (score 1):

If you switch to [Paludis](http://paludis.exherbo.org/), which is an alternative package manager for Gentoo (i.e. a replacement for `emerge`), you can probably set up a [hook](http://paludis.exherbo.org/configuration/hooks.html) to do that.

Comment: Can `paludis` work with `catalyst`?

Comment: I don't know.  I've never tried `catalyst`.