# Using package.env for phase hooks

Tags: gentoo, emerge

Following [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126335/39172) I've set up a simple file `/etc/portage/env/echo.conf`:

```
post_pkg_postinst()
{
    echo "updating $P to $PV"
}
```

with the line

```
sys-apps/util-linux echo.conf
```

in `/etc/portage/package.env`

Now when emerge tries to update `util-linux` I get the following error:

```
!!! Problem in 'sys-apps/util-linux' dependencies.
!!! "/etc/portage/env/echo.conf", line 2: Invalid token '(' (not '=') portage.exception                                                                ... done!
"/etc/portage/env/echo.conf", line 2: Invalid token '(' (not '=')
```

with line 2 being the function declaration `post_pkg_postinst()`.

My portage setup:

```
sys-apps/portage-2.2.20::gentoo was built with the following:
USE="(ipc) -build -doc -epydoc (-selinux) -xattr" ABI_X86="64" LINGUAS="-ru" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_3 (-pypy) -python3_4"
```

Comment: To follow the example corrrectly, remove the `.conf`

Answer (score 1):

`env/*` files are parsed with *python*, not *bash*, thus the error message.

AFAIK, the only place to put bash code is `portage/bashrc`, but do NOT try to override built-in functions like `src_configure`, etc.. Hooks on phases needs to be setup via checking `$EBUILD_PHASE` var.

And to give your hooks some structure you may try your luck with [bashrc-mv](https://github.com/vaeth/portage-bashrc-mv/).

Comment: In addition to /etc/portage/bashrc, files like /etc/portage/env/sys-libs/glibc are also Bash source codes

Comment: @atomsymbol yes, that is true, `/etc/portage/env/` is actually a mix of `make.conf`-like snippets parsed by python and shell script snippets sourced by bash. `man 5 portage` explains more.